# Python join on byte array

Tags: python, micropython

I need to loop through an array of byte arrays and then select a matching element from a dictionary. However my attempt to join the byte array fails:

```
roms = {
  "\xff\xfe\x88\x84\x16\x03\xd1":"living_room",
  "\x10\xe5x\xd5\x01\x08\x007":"bed_room"
}

devices = [bytearray(b'(\xff\xfe\x88\x84\x16\x03\xd1'), bytearray(b'\x10\xe5x\xd5\x01\x08\x007')]
for device in devices:
  DEV = "".join(device)
  print(roms[DEV])

>> TypeError: sequence item 0: expected str instance, int found
```

So it appears that you can't join an integer, is there another way?

## UPDATE 1

With much help and patience from @falsetrue, I have managed to join the array. However the resulting string still throws a key error when I attempt to get the devices dictionary item:

```
roms = {
  "\xff\xfe\x88\x84\x16\x03\xd1":"living_room",
  "\x10\xe5x\xd5\x01\x08\x007":"bed_room"
}

devices = [bytearray(b'(\xff\xfe\x88\x84\x16\x03\xd1'), bytearray(b'\x10\xe5x\xd5\x01\x08\x007')]

for device in devices:
  DEV = str(bytes(device)).strip('b').strip("'").strip('(') # > this results in: \xff\xfe\x88\x84\x16\x03\xd1 - but still gives keyError
  #DEV = bytes(device).lstrip(b'(') # > This results in: b'\xff\xfe\x88\x84\x16\x03\xd1' - keyError
  print(DEV)
  print(roms["\xff\xfe\x88\x84\x16\x03\xd1"])
  print(roms[DEV])
  print()

>> \xff\xfe\x88\x84\x16\x03\xd1
>> living_room
>> KeyError: \xff\xfe\x88\x84\x16\x03\xd1
```

## UPDATE 2

Here's the device info:

```
release='1.3.0.b1', 
version='v1.8.6-379-gc44ebac on 2017-01-13', 
machine='WiPy with ESP32'
```

**Maybe someone else with a WIPY2 can verify this for me?**

Comment: Sounds like an X-Y problem.  There is no reason to "join" a byte array as you've shown it.  You're not even joining two together.  Please explain more.  Also, shouldn't your keys in `roms` be bytes strings?  For example: `b'\xff\xfe...'`.  If they were, and `devices` were also byte strings, then `roms[devce]` would just work.

Comment: I didn't suggest to use `str`; it will add `b'...'` and escape bytes; It will make situtation worse; don't do that!

Comment: Just for reference, what version of Micropython is this - pyboard, WiPy, etc?

Comment: @nekomatic - 'WiPy', release='1.3.0.b1', version='v1.8.6-379-gc44ebac on 2017-01-13', machine='WiPy with ESP32'

Comment: OK, that's worth mentioning in any further questions. The original CC3200 based WiPy had a significantly cut-down version of MicroPython compared to the pyboard reference version, but it looks as if the ESP32 WiPy is closer to the reference.

Comment: @falsetrue - using DEV = bytes(device).lstrip(b'(') the result is b'\xff\xfe\x88\x84\x16\x03\xd1' - the b prefix is still there and the single speechmarks also have to be removed.

Comment: `b`, `'` are not parts of the bytes' content. They are they when they are printed. try this: `print(b'a')` and `print(b'a'.length)`. I hope it make sense.

Answer (score 1):

### If you're using Python 3.x:

You can decode the bytes to str using [`bytes.decode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) (or [`bytearray.decode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytearray.decode))

```
devices = [bytearray(b'\xff\xfe\x88\x84\x16\x03\xd1'),
           bytearray(b'\x10\xe5x\xd5\x01\x08\x007')]
for device in devices:
    DEV = device.decode('latin1')  # Use bytes.decode to convert to str
                                   # (or bytearray.decode)
    print(roms[DEV])
```

prints

```
living_room
bed_room
```

---

BTW, I removed `(` in byte literal.

```
devices = [bytearray(b'(\xff\xfe\x88\x84\x16\x03\xd1'), ...
                       ^
```

---

**UPDATE**

### If you're using Python 2.x:

Convert the `device` to `bytes` using `bytes` function:

```
for device in devices:
    DEV = bytes(device)
    print(roms[DEV])
```

Comment: Thanks so much for helping, but when I run that I get: "AttributeError: 'bytearray' object has no attribute 'decode'"

Comment: @crankshaft, How about `DEV = bytes(device).decode('latin1') ` ?

Comment: Made some progress, that line does not error, but when I try and use the DEV to get the dictionary device I get another error: "KeyError: (�����"

Comment: @crankshaft, I misunderstood you are using Python 3.x. I updated the answer, please check it out. In short, try `DEV = bytes(device)`. micropython seems not fully implemented Python 3.x.

Comment: @crankshaft, As I wrote in the answer, there is a extra `(` in the bytearray literal. Was it intentional?

Comment: appreciate your patience, using that method I get "KeyError: b'(\xff\xfe\x88\x84\x16\x03\xd1'", the ( in the binary literal was the result of dumping the device list from a sensor.

Comment: @crankshaft, What do you want to get if there's no match? try this: `print(roms.get(DEV, 'NO MATCH'))` to print `NO MATCH` if there's no matched item in the dictionary.

Comment: problem is the result of DEV = bytes(device) is "b'(\xff\xfe\x88\x84\x16\x03\xd1" and this is not the same key as the devices which is "\xff\xfe\x88\x84\x16\x03\xd1". the binary prefix and opening bracket should not be part of the string.

Comment: @crankshaft, Does `device = ...` come from externally or just written by you? If you write it yourself, you should just use string literal (not byte literal) as you said. Also make sure `(` is not there.  If it comes from outside, convert it as done in the answer, and optionally you can strip `(` using `.strip(b'(')`.

Comment: the devices[] is dumped from a sensor I have no control over it. I also just discovered that the first element has an extra 'b(' prefix whereas the second only has 'b' - I think there is a bug in the driver library that is adding this (

Comment: @crankshaft, Then, `DEV = ...` line should be `DEV = bytes(device).lstrip(b'(').decode('latin1')` or `DEV = bytes(device).lstrip(b'(')`

Comment: Thanks, but that still does not work, see my update above, thanks so much for helping, I don't think this is going to work !

Comment: If I run this on repl.it then your first example worked immediatly, so I am guessing there is some problem with micropython: https://repl.it/FLCq

Comment: Micropython has only ever been a derivative of Python 3.x, so the edit about 2.x above should be removed. I can't find anything in the docs at http://docs.micropython.org/en/latest/pyboard/reference/constrained.html to say that Micropython differs from full Python 3.4 in its handling of `str` vs `bytes` but if in doubt, take this question to the Micropython forum: http://forum.micropython.org/